# Host name not being resolved properly in CentOS

Tags: linux

I am running CentOS on a virtual machine. My /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.50.17 192-168-50-17.openstacklocal 192-168-50-17
192.168.50.13 slave5
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search openstacklocal
nameserver 192.168.50.3
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

All pings are working properly. However, when I am trying to run the following command -

/usr/lib64/lustre/tests/llmount.sh, this is what I am getting:

```
Loading modules from /usr/lib64/lustre/tests/..
detected 1 online CPUs by sysfs
libcfs will create CPU partition based on online CPUs
debug=vfstrace rpctrace dlmtrace neterror ha config               ioctl super lfsck
subsystem_debug=all -lnet -lnd -pinger
Formatting mgs, mds, osts
Format mds1: /tmp/lustre-mdt1
Format ost1: /tmp/lustre-ost1
mkfs.lustre: Cannot resolve hostname '192-168-50-17@tcp'.
mkfs.lustre: exiting with 1 (Operation not permitted)
```

I am running it as the root user. Any help on fixing this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why does your /etc/hosts file have what looks like an IP address with dashes (-) instead of dots (.)?  You probably just need to delete these lines from the (or the entire) /etc/hosts file.